# Python etree appending element after removing

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I want to be able to remove and append questions. This works in most cases, however appending doesn't work when the new question has the same q_nr as the question previously removed.

I'm having an xml file which looks like this.

```
<question>
    <q_nr>Q1</q_nr>
    <other />
</question
<question>
    <q_nr>Q2</q_nr>
    <other />
</question
```

function for removing:

```
def quest_del(request):
    q_nr = request.POST['deleteQnr']
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for quest in root.findall('project/question'):
        qt_nr = quest.find('q_nr').text
        if qt_nr == q_nr:
            for child in list(quest):
                quest.remove(child)
    for proj in root.findall('project'):
        for quest in proj.findall('question'):
            result = len(quest.getchildren())
            if result == 0:
                proj.remove(quest)
    tree.write(file_name)
```

function for appending:

```
def quest_adder(request):
    tree = ET.parse(source)
    proj = tree.getroot().find("project")
    q_text = ET.SubElement(proj, "question")
    q_text.text = "\n\t\t"
    q_text.tail = "\n\t"
    q_nr = ET.SubElement(q_text, q_nr)
    q_nr.text = request.POST['quest_nr']
    q_nr.tail = "\n\t\t"
    tree.write(filename)
```

Comment: Don't just say "appending doesn't work". Please be specific. What happens exactly? What is the expected result? You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: What happens is that the new <question> isn't written to the xml file when the <q_nr> is the same as the previously deleted <q_nr>. If the <q_nr> of the new question differs from the previously deleted one, the xml-file is updated. If another action is taken in between I can add a new <question> having the same <q_nr> as the previously deleted one.

Comment: Sorry to be a nag, but you still need to provide a **minimal but complete example that we can run**. Your functions take arguments that are not explained. What is `request`? What is `source`? What is `filename`? The XML file is not well-formed, and it has no `project` elements (which you look for in the code).